# Start an Alarm every 10 seconds with AlarmManager

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, alarmmanager

I'm making an android app and I want to activate an alarm every 10 minutes.

The problem is that the alarm is activated only one time.

Here is the code who launch the BroadcastReceiver :

```
public void CallAlarmReceiver(bool isRepeating, bool destroy)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        i.SetAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;

        AlarmManagerCompat.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(alarmManager, (int)AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)(Calendar.GetInstance(Android.Icu.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds), pi);
    }
```

Comment: I imagine you want to loop it right..? I don't see the parameter "isRepeating" used which I imagine you possibly overlooked

Comment: Dont pays attention to the paramètres, they are used after in the function but this part is not important.

Answer (score 0):

when broadcast received. call this method again.

Comment: That's what I did but I want this alarm work when the app is killer and I need the activity context to enqueue an alert which is not available when the app is killed...

Comment: then this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43253631/9932178

Comment: C'est intéressant mais je dois faire cela avec une alarme...

Comment: this is only for reference. you can add your alarm manager in this server or another approach in this service.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is to use a timer.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
{
    // Do something

    return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
});
```

Comment: You could use the Android Lifecyle to catch the app operations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/