# Android Rx Buffer Force Emit

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm writing a file logging utility, using Rx buffer, for my Android app.

```
        val logBuffer = PublishSubject.create<String>()

        logBuffer
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .buffer(10)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe {
                // write to file
            }
```

It works well in normal use cases. Now, I want the ability to write/flush logs, on some specific event e.g. app kill or a specific error occurrence, even when buffer is not filled. Needed help in implementing the force emission of buffer. In my search, I was unable to find any related thing and additionally I'm new to Rx.

Comment: If the app is "killed" how do you expect the process to complete this task?  An application is not gracefully shutdown in this circumstance.

Comment: @MarkKeen I think we can do some quick operations in onDestroy event.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "app kill" - there is no guarantee `onDestroy` is called https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473952/4252352

Comment: @MarkKeen App kill event is just an example. There can be any other event like a specific error occurrence in app code. The actual question is how to explicitly invoke a buffer emit.

Comment: " kill event is just an example." - Yes, the only one you mentioned in your question - so you don't care in this circumstance? Do any flushing, if attached to some lifecycle, in `onPause`

Comment: @MarkKeen another use case is when user logs out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230013/discussion-between-asim-panra-and-mark-keen).

Comment: just don't bother with the buffer - write line by line, appending a cyclic rolling log, or log files etc .. Can you provide evidence why the buffer is even required or adds value?

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm thinking of buffer to avoid writing to file on every log and instead do a number of logs at once. This is to have a smaller number of IO operations and better app performance.

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm thinking of buffer to avoid writing to file on every log and instead do a number of logs at once. This is to have a smaller number of IO operations and better app performance.

Comment: Well again, evidence, how chatty are your logs? How does it offer better app performance?  Are these simply assumptions? Having "pending" writes in memory is bound to lead to issues, especially as the buffer has to be "full" to emit -  probably will have less issues using `window` and filtering empty lists.?